# Split MySQL by new line

Tags: tcl, eggdrop

I have in my tcl script a mysql select qry, and this is vertical.
There are about 30 issues from the query with 3-6 letters.
I want to split it after 80 characters to a new line

```
set sql_network "SELECT `grp` FROM `name` WHERE `network` LIKE '$network'"
set result_network [mysqlsel $db_handle $sql_network -list]
putquick "PRIVMSG $channel :Results: \002$result_network\002"
```

I have this tested, but it does not work. I suspect it refers to the individual short words

```
set length [::textutil::adjust $result_network -length 80 -strictlength true]
```

Comment: You are aware that your query contains a potential SQL injection attack vulnerability?

Comment: nope why and who?

Comment: The issue is that if someone can set `network` to the string `' AND something_evil AND '' = '` then they can run all sorts of troublesome things. Alas, as far as I can see the mysqltcl package doesn't have good mitigations for this… so the right fix might instead be to switch to **tdbc::mysql**, but that has a different API so it is probably an intrusive fix.

Comment: i will check this, ths for info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `textutil::adjust` command returns the adjusted text. You need to do a bit more work before sending it out:

```
set LINE_LENGTH 80

set sql_network "SELECT `grp` FROM `name` WHERE `network` LIKE '$network'"
set result_network [mysqlsel $db_handle $sql_network -list]

set text [::textutil::adjust $result_network -length $LINE_LENGTH -strictlength true]
foreach line [split $text "\n"] {
    putquick "PRIVMSG $channel :Results: \002$line\002"
}
```